# Spring MVC - redirects me to my login fail mapping despite correct username and password

Tags: java, spring-mvc, authentication

Whenever I try to login to my application it uses my invalidLogin controller. I have a feeling that the problem is with my LoginConfig but im not sure what he problem is.
My LoginConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requiresChannel ()
            .anyRequest()
            .requiresSecure()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login-page").loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/login-pass",true).failureUrl("/login-fail").permitAll()
            .and().logout().invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login-page")
            .permitAll()
            .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
    @Autowired 
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;  

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder pe = new  BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(pe);

    }

}
```

Here is my login controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired UserLoginRepository userRepo;

    @RequestMapping(value="/login-page", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginForm() {
        System.out.println("welcome to log in page");
        return "security/login-form";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login-fail", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String invalidLogin(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("error", true);
        System.out.println("failed LOGIN");
        return "security/login-form";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login-pass", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String successLogin() { 
        System.out.println("success");
        return "deck-page";
    }
}
```

And finally my login form jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Login page</title>
<style>
.error {
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login page</h1>

<p>
<c:if test="${error == true}">
    <b class="error">Invalid login or password.</b>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${logout == true}">
    <b class="logout">You have been logged out.</b>
</c:if>
</p>

    <form action="/login" method="post">       
        <p>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>  
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>  
        </p>
        <input type="hidden"                        
            name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
    </form> 

</body>
</html>
```

So I know the controllers work as the the failed login work. In the run I have the following code to set a user up:

```
    BCryptPasswordEncoder pe = new  BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    Users user = new Users();
    user.setLogin("joe");
    user.setPassword(pe.encode("123456"));
    userRepo.save(user);
```

[Furthermore, checking my SQL I can see that it stores the the username and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jryQb.png)

Comment: Turn up logging for `org.springframework.security` to DEBUG and see what it says. (Also, your life will be simpler if you work with conventions instead of overriding them without a reason--the default login URL of `/login` works just fine.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would I go about using the default conventions? Excuse my naivety, this is how we learnt to do it at university. I have however looked at the log and it seems to think the user 'joe' doesn't exist. Is this an a database error? Here is a link to the [log](https://textuploader.com/152f4)

Comment: Just let the login form be `/login`, and don't specify anything at all after `formLogin()`. And yes, looking at the code you posted, you seem to have a `UserRepository` somewhere but nothing connecting it with `UserDetailsService`, so you're probably getting something like an in-memory temporary service.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yes I figured out yesterday there was nothing linking the user and UserDetailsService. I'll comment and mark as done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating a class that links my Users class so it can properly compare.

```
@Service
public class TopTrumpUserDetailsServices implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserLoginRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        TopTrumpUser u = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        return new User(u.getUsername(), u.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

}
```